# How to trace a dialog that pops up repeatedly?

Tags: windows

The standard warning and error dialogs in Windows. Is there a way to trace them (to find out what process is creating them)?

I have an error that pops up after being closed, but looking at the event logs, there seems to be no trace of the error. In a few Google searches I found that many other people have gotten the same error, for no apparent reason, and that the entire internet seems to be filled with people advertising for some software called ms-errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) from the [SysInternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) suite to list the processes and get their information.

The tool has a drag-and-drop button to find a window's process.
Once you drop it on the pop-up window it should show the associated process in the procexp view.
You can then right click on the process and get details.

---

You could also describe the error pop-up you get; someone here might be able to give you a more exact solution.